# Timed while loop not terminating

Tags: java, timer, while-loop, timertask

Running this code, I would expect it to increment the test variable for 5 seconds and then finish.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Test {
    private static boolean running;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        long time = 5 * 1000;       // converts time to milliseconds
        long test = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        running = true;

        // Uses an anonymous class to set the running variable to false
        Timer timer = new Timer(); 
        timer.schedule( new TimerTask() { 
            @Override
            public void run() { running = false; }
        }, time );

        while( running ) {
            test++;
        }

        timer.cancel();
        System.out.println( test );
    }
}
```

However when I run it the program doesn't end (I assume, I have given it a reasonable amount of time). However if I change the while loop to

```
    while( running ) {
        System.out.println();
        test++;
    }
```

The program finishes in the expected amount of time (and prints out a lot of lines). I don't understand. Why does this behaviour occur?

Comment: What if you make running `volatile`?

Comment: I just tested your code using JDK 7 with IntelliJ 11 and both versions finished in a few seconds.  What are you using to run?

Comment: @AndyTurner wow, I've never come across the volatile keyword before. Thats makes the code work. Thanks!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Java 8 update 45

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Java Memory Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model) there's no guarantee when non-volatile field will be visible from another thread. In your case your main method is JIT compiled and JIT-compiler reasonably assume that as *current* thread does not modify the `running` variable in a loop, then we should not bother reading it on every iteration and convert the loop to the infinite one. There's even [FindBugs warning](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#SP_SPIN_ON_FIELD) regarding this case.

When you add a `System.out.println` call, seems that JIT compiler cannot inline it, so it cannot be sure that this method does not modify the `running` variable, thus it switches off the field reading optimization. However that should not be considered as problem solution: it's possible that newer versions of Java will be smarter and optimize your loop even if you have `System.out.println` inside.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it links additional information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Lets get closer into your code...

If you debug your code, it will work. That's because you will only see one thread and no cache. Java can use thread-based cache mechanisms. You need to read and write it into main memory.

So if you use `volatile` keyword on your running variable, jvm will see it as editable by multiple threads, and it shouldn't be cached.

Therefore in your situation solution is adding `volatile` to your running variable.

Answer (score 2):

You are updating the `running` variable in a different thread from your `main` method. The Java Memory Model is such that you are not guaranteed to see updates to non-volatile variables in different threads.

The easiest solution is to make the variable `volatile`: this forces the 'current' value of the variable to be checked when the thread accesses it.

Other solutions include using `AtomicBoolean` instead of `boolean`, and wrapping access to `running` in mutually `synchronized` blocks (i.e. the code that accesses `running` is synchronized on the same monitor as the code which updates it).

I strongly recommend that you pick up a copy of Java Concurrency In Practice, which describes this problem in detail.